# Hbase filterlist MUST_PASS_ONE always evaluates all?

Tags: hbase, hbase-filter

from the hbase [docs](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) we see that :

> FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE evaluates non-lazily: all filters
>   are always evaluated.

Now, anyone can tell you that T | F | F ... = T , i.e. we can stop on the first `True` value encountered. I was wondering if anyone knows why the filterlist does not replicate this behaviour?